# how to extract information from a list of strings with various lists in python

Tags: python, string, split

I have a `splits` list of strings as follows:

```
splits = ['Heading_Error(deg):<br>    base = 60.760321610086216<br>    feature = 119.09070043133725<br>    scene', '5G21A6P00L4100037:1566448100150275<br>    object', "['f528bf65-9028-443d-8288-1efcd5c837cd', 'eb71c9c8-3924-4038-822f-0ac0508eb02c', 'e1f2c84b-fb37-4e33-8b5b-4f37d354d326']<br>    cloud_uuid_feature = ['5G21A6P00L4100037:1566448099:1566448119-lidar_roof_left-1566448100150275', '5G21A6P00L4100037:1566448099:1566448119-lidar_roof_left-1566448100150275', '5G21A6P00L4100037:1566448099:1566448119-lidar_roof_left-1566448100150275']<br>"]
```

How can I extract the following fields?

```
scene = "5G21A6P00L4100037:1566448100150275"
objects = [
   'f528bf65-9028-443d-8288-1efcd5c837cd',
   'eb71c9c8-3924-4038-822f-0ac0508eb02c',
   'e1f2c84b-fb37-4e33-8b5b-4f37d354d326'
]
cloud_uuid_feature = [
   '5G21A6P00L4100037:1566448099:1566448119-lidar_roof_left-1566448100150275', 
   '5G21A6P00L4100037:1566448099:1566448119-lidar_roof_left-1566448100150275', 
   '5G21A6P00L4100037:1566448099:1566448119-lidar_roof_left-1566448100150275'
]
```

objects are a list of strings,
cloud_uuid_feature is a list of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping the structure of your message holds good.
I am joining the splits into a single string and find the necessary data.

```
import re
st=''.join(splits)
scene = re.findall('scene([^<]*)<br>',st)[0]
/// result '5G21A6P00L4100037:1566448100150275'

objects_str = re.findall('object\[([^\]]*)\]',st)[0]
objects=[x.strip().strip("'") for x in objects_str.split(',')]
/// result ['f528bf65-9028-443d-8288-1efcd5c837cd', 'eb71c9c8-3924-4038-822f-0ac0508eb02c', 'e1f2c84b-fb37-4e33-8b5b-4f37d354d326']

clouds_str = re.findall('cloud_uuid_feature.*\[([^\]]*)\]',st)[0]
cloud_uuid_feature = [x.strip().strip("'") for x in clouds_str.split(',')]
/// result ['5G21A6P00L4100037:1566448099:1566448119-lidar_roof_left-1566448100150275', '5G21A6P00L4100037:1566448099:1566448119-lidar_roof_left-1566448100150275', '5G21A6P00L4100037:1566448099:1566448119-lidar_roof_left-1566448100150275']
```